# tensorflow lstm - Output tensors of a Functional model must be the output of a TensorFlow `Layer` (thus holding past layer metadata)

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, translation, encoder-decoder

So I am trying to create a translation model and am stuck with an error for which I am not able to find any solution.

here is the code that I am trying.

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, LSTM, Dense
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data_path='new_mar.txt'            # Its a tab separated file.
with open(data_path,'r',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    lines=f.read().split('\n')
    print(len(lines))
for line in lines[:min(num_samples,len(lines)-1)]:
    input_text,output_text,_=line.split('\t')
    output_text='\t'+output_text+'\n'
    input_texts.append(input_text)
    output_texts.append(output_text)
    for char in input_text:
        if char not in input_characters:
            input_characters.add(char)
    for char1 in output_text:
        if char1 not in output_characters:
            output_characters.add(char1)

input_characters=sorted(list(input_characters))
output_characters=sorted(list(output_characters))
num_encoder_token=len(input_characters)
num_decoder_token=len(output_characters)
max_encoder_seq_length=max([len(txt) for txt in input_texts])
max_decoder_seq_length=max([len(txt) for txt in output_texts])

input_token_idx=dict([(char,i) for i,char in enumerate(input_characters)])
output_token_idx=dict([(char,i) for i,char in enumerate(output_characters)])

encoder_input_data=np.zeros((len(input_texts),max_encoder_seq_length,num_encoder_token),dtype='float32')
decoder_input_data=np.zeros((len(output_texts),max_decoder_seq_length,num_decoder_token),dtype='float32')
decoder_output_data=np.zeros((len(output_texts),max_decoder_seq_length,num_decoder_token),dtype='float32')

for i,(input_text,output_text) in enumerate(zip(input_texts,output_texts)):
    for t,char in enumerate(input_text):
                encoder_input_data[i, t, input_token_idx[char]]=1
    encoder_input_data[i,t+1:,input_token_idx[' ']]=1
    for t,char in enumerate(output_text):
                decoder_input_data[i,t,output_token_idx[char]]=1
                if t>0:
                    decoder_output_data[i,t-1,output_token_idx[char]]=1
    decoder_input_data[i,t+1:,output_token_idx[' ']]=1
    decoder_output_data[i,t:,output_token_idx[' ']]=1

encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None, num_encoder_token))
encoder = LSTM(latent_dim, return_state=True)
encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = encoder(encoder_input_data)
encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]

decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None, num_decoder_token))
decoder_lstm = LSTM(latent_dim, return_state=True)
decoder_outputs, _, _ = decoder_lstm(decoder_input_data,
                                     initial_state=encoder_states)
decoder_dense = Dense(num_decoder_token, activation='softmax')

outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)

model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], outputs)
```

So here at the last line it is throwing me the following error:-
[image]
[image]

I tried reading Keras functional API but that also didn't help.

Please can someone help me fix this error and explain a bit why i got this error, where I went wrong and what I could have done to avoid this error.